# RxJava How to retry partial in chain flatmap

Tags: rx-java2

```
Observable.just()
    .flatMap()
    .flatMap()
  <-Back to This line-----|
    .flatMap()            |
    .flatMap()            |
                          |
    .flatMap()            |
    .flatMap()            |             
    ------------------->Error Occur
    .flatMap()
    .flatMap()
```

I have a chain of flatMap, in one flatMap, when it emit error, I'd like to back to partial of the flatMap chain, I try use cache and retry operator, but it can't be stopped by dispose()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to turn them into an inner flow, for example:

```java
Observable.just()
    .flatMap()
    .flatMap(v -> 
        Observable.just(v)
        .flatMap()            
        .flatMap()            
                          
        .flatMap()            
        .flatMap()                         
        .retry()
    )
    .flatMap()
    .flatMap()
```